# язык сайта по умолчанию

Tags: yii2

ребят как поставить по умолчанию язык сайта, точнее при загрузке сайта она загружалась на определенном языке

Comment: а можно по конкретнее....

Comment: если вы хотите просто менять язык на сайте,исходя из местоположения,или изначально выбранного,просто используйте if(lang ==  "russian"){...}и все

Comment: хочу чтобы сайт подгружался на определенном языке, как только наберешь адрес

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы поставить русскую локаль, необходимо в конфигурационном файле вписать следующую строку в массив

```
'language' => 'ru-RU',
```

Если Вы используете advanced-шаблон yii2, путь к файлу следующий: `/common/config/main.php`

Если Вы используете basic-шаблон yii2, путь к файлу следующий: `/config/web.php`

Comment: действительно)) поправил